# Cygwin: Error while linking .lib files

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, linker

I'm new with `Cygwin` and currently I'm trying to build a little project which would encrypt some files.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to build the `.cpp` with the command:

`gcc test.cpp -I /cygdrive/c/OpenSSL-Win32/include/ -L/cygdrive/c/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/MinGW -lcrypto -lssl`

(OpenSSL is installed at `cygdrive/c/OpenSSL-Win32`) I get the error:

`/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I can't understand why It can't to find the libraries, because I clearly have `libssl.lib`  and `libcrypto.lib` there. Sorry if my question sounds silly I'm with all this. Thanks.

Comment: What's `.lib`? A windows import library? If so, try naming it `.dll.a`

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to title "*xyz doesn't work*" when it clearly does ... something is wrong in your environment and/or with your expectations.

Comment: I'm using cygwin, should not it be able to link .lib files?

Comment: whats result when running 'ls of /cygdrive/c/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/MinGW' ?

Comment: `capi.lib  dasync.lib  libcrypto.lib  libcrypto-1_1.def  libssl.lib  libssl-1_1.def    openssl.lib  ossltest.lib  padlock.lib  VC`

Comment: I also checked the permissions and set them `777` just for the test, but it didn't help

Comment: try -llibcrypto.lib -llibssl.lib